# Guide me with this css animation code technique

Tags: html, css

Can you tell me what is done by `position: numbers %` in css animation.
How these numbers are working?

```
body{
  font-family:'Merriweather Sans';
  background:white;
}
#test{
  background:linear-gradient(270deg, #36bf9c, #368ebf, #df5a5f, #eea965);
  color:white;
  background-size:600% 600%;
  padding:20px 450px;
  position:static;
  font-size:40px;
  font-family:"Merriweather Sans";
  animation:gradient 60s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes gradient{
0%{
  background-position: 0% 50%;

}
50%{
  background-position:100% 50%;
}
100%{
  background-position:0% 50%;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @IsabelInc - guidance

Comment: Sure. I meant what effects are you trying to achieve with the percentages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**0%** means the CSS will be applied at the start

**50%** means when half of the specified time will pass ( here 30s)

**100%** means when the full time passes.

And the animations can't happen instantly so it will go with a lot of transition states but at these times the CSS will be the specified one.

Answer (score 0):

The background-size is 600%, which means 6 times the size of visual area (#test div)it is displayed in. The background is set up as a gradient. By moving this background left to right and back, it makes the colors change in an animated fashion.

I have added an extra div in the example to show the gradient.

```css
body{
  font-family:'Merriweather Sans';
  background:white;
}
#test{
  background:linear-gradient(270deg, #36bf9c, #368ebf, #df5a5f, #eea965);
  color:white;
  background-size:600% 600%;
  padding:20px 450px;
  position:static;
  font-size:40px;
  font-family:"Merriweather Sans";
  animation:gradient 60s ease infinite;
}

#backgroundImage {
  background:linear-gradient(270deg, #36bf9c, #368ebf, #df5a5f, #eea965);
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
   background-size:100% 100%;
 }

@keyframes gradient{
0%{
  background-position: 0% 50%;

}
50%{
  background-position:100% 50%;
}
100%{
  background-position:0% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<br>
<div id="backgroundImage"></div>
```